# Does old pci devices harm my new computer?

Tags: windows-7, computer-building, pci, screen-recorder

I have an old device that can be used also as a recorder (pci device with an output of 480p) called "KWorld Plus TV Analog Lite PCI" and has these requirements:

> - Intel Pentium IV 2.0 GHz or equivalent AMD CPU or higher
>
>   - 256MB RAM of system memory or above
>   - PCI 2.2 Compliant Slot
>   - Graphics Card with 64 MB memory or above (must support DirectX 9.0c)
>   - Sound Card (AC97 compatible sound card)
>   - 2GB free HD space for recording
>   - Microsoft Windows (r) XP SP2 / Windows XP MCE 2005
>
> For Microsoft Media Center, Time-shifting
>
> - Intel Pentium IV 3.0GHz or equivalent AMD CPU or higher
>
>   - DDR400 1024MB RAM of system memory or above
>   - Graphics Card
>   - Sound Card must be compatible with Windows Vista
>   - Windows XP MCE 2005 / Windows Vista Premium above

I'm using Windows 7 64 bits in my computer which has: processor Intel i5, 8GB RAM, on-board graphics card.

My brother suspects it can do harm to the computer because the TV display wasn't ok at all (there was a thin line of image imperfection), but I don't want to use it to watch tv, all I want to do is to record the monitor display (like any game capture device), and I never tried that feature before.

What are exactly the posibilities? Is there actually a risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PCI board is physically OK (i.e. it's not doing any weirdness electrically) and you can find the Windows 7 64 bit drivers for it, then there shouldn't be any "problems". At most your computer won't boot with the card in it (removing the card would allow it to boot), but chances are the "thin line of image imperfection" you saw was due to a some output issue (i.e. the image pushed to the display, not the images traversing the PCI bus) and shouldn't cause any issues in regards to recording or using the device on the machine you have.

Just test the card out; plug it in, turn on the machine and make sure Windows recognizes the device. If the machine boots with the card in it and nothing pops or sizzles, then you're biggest hurdle will be finding the right drivers for it.

Hope that helps.